# hide a frame after 3 seconds/ by calling a function (need to done in both way)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I create 2 frames in the same window with some attributes in it. now am able to call it separately or can display both

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import time
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def frame1(self,Dialog):
        self.frame = QtGui.QFrame(Dialog)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 20, 311, 391))
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("frame"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 180, 72, 23))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "omniOS", None))

    def frame2(self,Dialog):
        self.frame_2 = QtGui.QFrame(Dialog)
        self.frame_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 311, 391))
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("frame_2"))
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.frame_2)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 230, 72, 31))
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.frame_2)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 230, 113, 33))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Login", None))


    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(391, 437)
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "OmniOS", None))
        self.frame1(Dialog)
        self.frame2(Dialog)

if __name__=="__main__":
    ui=Ui_Dialog()
    import sys
    a = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui.setupUi(w)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

what I need to do is, I need to get the first window after a 3 second I need to get the second window + hide the first one without overlapping it

```
 self.frame1(Dialog) # call this when the program start
 self.frame2(Dialog) # call this after 3 second self.frame1(Dialog)
```

Any help would be appreciated ThankYou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That a code works does not imply that it is correct, for example I see that you have combined 2 codes generated by Qt Designer and obviously they are going to overlap, the correct thing is to have 2 windows that are exchanged as shown below using QTimer.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import time
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog1(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        self.frame = QtGui.QFrame(Dialog)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 20, 311, 391))
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("frame"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 180, 72, 23))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "omniOS", None))
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(391, 437)
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "OmniOS", None))


class Ui_Dialog2(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        self.frame_2 = QtGui.QFrame(Dialog)
        self.frame_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 311, 391))
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("frame_2"))
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.frame_2)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 230, 72, 31))
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.frame_2)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 230, 113, 33))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Login", None))
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(391, 437)
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "OmniOS", None))


class Dialog1(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_Dialog1):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


class Dialog2(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_Dialog2):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)



if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    a = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w1 = Dialog1()
    w2 = Dialog2()

    def on_timeout():
        w1.hide()
        w2.show()

    w1.show()
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(3000, on_timeout)
    sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

Comment: can you also give some explanation as a comment what the Class Dailog1,Dailog2 will do

Comment: @abhikrishnan read http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html

Comment: Thanks for the document

Comment: Hi can you help one of My friend with this   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52962981/cantt-hide-a-window-when-window-size-maximized-in-pyqt?noredirect=1

Comment: Thank You very much brother I need to learn Qt can you help me. how to start and where to learn it, perfectly

Comment: @abhikrishnan Read the Qt docs and the examples of Qt and PyQt, in addition to the thousands of SO answer.

Comment: Ok, brother Thanks for the answer on my friend Question. ThankYOU  for your great support

Comment: Hi, if changed the self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 20, 311, 391)) to self.frame.showMaximized() then its not displying it properly

Comment: @abhikrishnan showMaximized is for windows is not for widgets.

Comment: Then How can we do it Then ?

Comment: @abhikrishnan keep experimenting, so you will learn more, try with show in instead of shomMazimixed.

Comment: Yes Brother both show and showMaximized() want to apply it in the Dailog2 class Got it. ThankYou, but facing a small issue its not showing full screen . will fix it Thank You