# Cant't hide a window when window size maximized in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

i have two windows,i want to hide it after three seconds by using Qt timer,but its overlapping...its probably occurs when window size sets to 
 "showMaximized"

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt, QPoint

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)



class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.showMaximized()
        Form.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(450, 317, 300, 61))
        self.label.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("font: 75 60pt \"Tlwg Mono\";color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "omniOS", None))

class Ui_Dialog1(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.showMaximized()
        Dialog.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"))
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(Dialog)
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))


class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

class Dialog1(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_Dialog1):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
    def paintEvent(self, event):
         painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
         painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.white))
         painter.drawArc(QtCore.QRectF(640, 330, 35, 35), 0, 5750)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w1=Dialog()
    w2=Dialog1()




    def on_timeout():
        w1.hide()
        w2.show()

    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(3000, on_timeout)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

what I need to do is, I need to get
 second window after three seconds when 
size sets to  maximized.

```
 Form.showMaximized()
```

This change to (form.resize) its working what i expected.
  Any help plz

Comment: nope..bro at the same time those two windows are open...its overlapped

Comment: when i try to call w1.show() i can see only w2....its will open together and closed one after 3sec. i need w1 first and after 3sec w2.....Any suggestion?

Comment: Bro one more doubt when i try to w1 maximized i can't visible inserted labels

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52966004/i-try-to-maximized-the-window-i-cant-visible-labels-button-in-pyqt

Comment: please check the question too bro

Comment: do not use the comments to notify about other questions, that is not your objective, when I have time I will try to help you, or probably another user will have helped you. :-)

Comment: yaa i thought you can easily help me... when i  asked a question that so i mentioned  as a comment. yaa right that not my objective.Sorry for the inconvenience and also thanks for your  valuable time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not observe that w1 is closed because w2 is above w1, but if it is working, so you point out in the comments I understand that you want initially only visible w1 and after 3 seconds w2 is displayed and w1 is hidden, considering that the solution is the following:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w1=Dialog()
    w2=Dialog1()
    w2.hide()
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(3000, w1.hide)
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(3000, w2.showMaximized)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```